# ImageView as background in a cell

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to use an imageView as a background for a listView cell. The picture that i want to display is bigger than the size of the cell. I can't figure out how to make the imageView match the size of the cell and prevent it to be stretched to the size of the picture.

Bonus point: Since only a part of my picture will be displayed, is it possible to move the picture in the imageView so the center is displayed ?

Comment: why not use the image as background for cell why imageview.Do it serve any special purpose?

Comment: Just use the `ImageView` as the first element of your cell as a  `RelativeLayout` and give it the `width` and `height` to `match_parent`.

Comment: @Pramod Yadav Background images will always stretch to fit the view. I want to keep the original picture ratio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
   <ImageView
    ...
    android:id="@+id/photo"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/cell"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/cell"
    .../>
```

to have your image centered in your imageview, even if your image is bigger than your cell.

To use an imageView as a Background picture, why not using a RelativeLayout with an ImageView in it and then the content of your cell in a LinearLayout?

```
<RelativeLayout>

<ImageView
        ...
        android:id="@+id/photo"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/cell"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/cell"
        .../>

<LinearLayout
 android:id="@+id/cell>
//Content of your cell
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: +1 because of the centerCrop, however, when applying your solution, the cell is still resized to the size of the picture. I want the imageView to "cut" the picture and match the size of my cell.

Comment: It works. Actually I was using a custom ImageView and it was messing up with some align functions. Seeing your answer helped to see that something was wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
 android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```